# how to jump from one jframe to other without losing the incremented value in jlabel

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a restaurant management system in this program i'm facing a problem.
I have an incrementing counter variable in `jlabel` which works correctly, but when I jump to another `jframe` the incremented value of jlabel gets lost. I don't want to lose that value until the program gets closed.

Here is the code of Increment in `jlabel` and the button on which it works

```
private void token()
{     
    int token=Integer.parseInt(lbltoken.getText());
    String add=String.valueOf(token+1);
    lbltoken.setText(add);

}

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
    token();
}
```

Comment: *"jump from one jframe to other"* 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle. 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by " jump to another jframe"? How are you doing this in terms of Java code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your 'add' String a global variable.

As soon as the 'token()' method has finished executing, all local variables within that method are destroyed.

Comment: how do i make it global i'm not getting it can you give an example please

Comment: To make a variable global, you declare it at the top of your class.

Class Apple() {
         
    String add = "";

     public Apple() {

     } 

     //Methods below

}

Answer (score 0):

in frame 1st you have a label.
let's suppose your first class name is Apple.
and you have a button and jlable named pricelbl with a value.

now you want that value in 2nd class.

in class 1st set a actionListener to the button. suppose button name is btnFile and your 2nd class name in Banana.

```
    btnFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           Banana.main(null);   //this will open your 2nd frame

           // here you can also use
            new Banana.setVisible(true);    // this will also open your 2nd frame
        }
    });
```

now in 2nd frame just write.

```
Apple.pricelbl.getText();  //this will get your incremented value in second frame
```

but make sure that your label is public in class  Apple

Comment: and to make a variable global just declare it in class.